# Identify sequences of the same number in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix A

```
A= [0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 3 3;
    2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 0;
```

As you can see, there are consecutive numbers in it; notice for example the `2 2 2 2` on the first and second row.

For each number occuring in this matrix (or at least for every number from 1 to the maximum number in my matrix) I want to have an output matrix that indicates sequences of this number and this number only in the original matrix.

So for example, for `1`: there are three consecutive numbers on the first row and three on the second row: I want to indicate this in the first output matrix as follows:

```
Matrix 1 = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0;
             0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0]
```

Same for number `2`:

```
Matrix 2 = [ 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
             1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

and `3`:

```
Matrix 3 = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2;
             0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0]
```

As you can see, each output matrix shows counting forward for the consecutive occurrences of a number.

So in this case, I have 3 output matrices because matrix A has 3 as the biggest value there.

Comment: @Gunther Struyf: Mr Struyf, Thanks you for your addition to make clear my question. I really need help to make a code of this problem

Comment: what happens for something like this: [1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 0] ?

Comment: this will be 2 matrix : the first which only considers value "1", 1st matrix= [ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 0 ] and the second matrix which only considers value "2". 2nd matrix = [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0].

Comment: @Febri Dwi Laksono: Dan means what happens if the numbers are not consecutive. Because in your example matrix, there is only one sequence of consecutive occurrences of the same number.

Comment: What about this: [1 2 1 2 1] if you want to get [1 0 2 0 3] and [0 1 0 2 0] as a result then the answers below are perfect. If not then what should the result be for this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
A= [0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 3 3;
    2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 0];

result = arrayfun(@(b) (A == b).*cumsum((A == b),2),nonzeros(unique(A)), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

For this example, there will be 3 submatrices in the variable result.

```
result = 

    [2x14 double]
    [2x14 double]
    [2x14 double]
```

To access them, use the following syntax:

```
result{1}
result{2}
result{3}
```

Then you get:

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     0
```

**~edit~**
If, as asked in the comments, A is a 3D matrix, this code works just the same, but the structure of result is a bit different:

```
result = 
    [2x14x2 double]
    [2x14x2 double]
    [2x14x2 double]
```

To access these matrices, use for instance

```
result{1}(:,:,1) % for the results of comparing A(:,:,1) with value 1
result{1}(:,:,2) % for the results of comparing A(:,:,2) with value 1
```

Comment: this is very similar to what [@mathematician1975](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11633990/97160) did, only written as a one-liner. Not fully vectorized (ARRAYFUN has a loop after all), but its as compact as it gets. +1 to you both I guess..

Comment: Actually, there is a certain similarity (use of cumsum on logicals), but please note that this version automatically extracts the different values in A and delivers results for each of them. Thanks for the hint on the loop in arrayfun, I actually never thought about it.

Comment: @H.Muster : Mr Muster, What should I do when Matrix A is 3D matrix. I feel difficult to modify, please help me to modify your code Mr..

Answer (score 4):

**Edited because the question changed**

This is nowhere near to optimal but will do what you want

```
 V = 1;
 C = A' == V;
 D = cumsum(C).*C
 E = D'
```

now `E` will be `Matrix1` in your example. Change `V` to 2 and 3 to obtain `Matrix2` and `Matrix3`. If you have something like

```
 A = [2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2]
```

then you will get

```
 [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6]
```

so it may not be what you want. It is not clear from your question if this is the case or not, but if not tell me and I will delete the answer

Answer (score 4):

This is a loop-based solution to get you started:

```
A = [
  0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 3 3;
  2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 0
];

mx = max(A(:));
AA = cell(mx,1);
for num=1:mx
    AA{num} = zeros(size(A));
    for r=1:size(A,1)
        idx = ( A(r,:) == num );
        AA{num}(r,idx) = sum(idx):-1:1;
    end
end
```

The result:

```
>> AA{1}
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     2     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
>> AA{2}
ans =
     0     0     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
>> AA{3}
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1     0
```

---

### EDIT:

Updated code to work on matrix with three dimensions:

```
A = zeros(2,7,2);
A(:,:,1) = [2 2 2 0 0 1 1 ; 0 0 2 2 2 1 1];
A(:,:,2) = [1 1 2 2 2 0 0 ; 0 1 1 0 2 2 2];

mx = max(A(:));
AA = cell(mx,1);
for num=1:mx
    AA{num} = zeros(size(A));
    for p=1:size(A,3)
        for r=1:size(A,1)
            idx = ( A(r,:,p) == num );
            AA{num}(r,idx,p) = 1:sum(idx);
        end
    end
end
```

The result:

```
%# contains consecutive numbers corresponding to number 1 in all slices
>> AA{1}
ans(:,:,1) =
     0     0     0     0     0     1     2
     0     0     0     0     0     1     2
ans(:,:,2) =
     1     2     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     2     0     0     0     0

%# contains consecutive numbers corresponding to number 2 in all slices
>> AA{2}
ans(:,:,1) =
     1     2     3     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3     0     0
ans(:,:,2) =
     0     0     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     2     3
```

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: you seem to have changed the count to forward counting. Easily fixed, use `1:sum(idx)` instead of `sum(idx):-1:1`.

Comment: sir, what should I do, if the Matrix A is Matrix which has three dimension?, I feel difficult to modify your code. can you help me?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: can you give us an example of input and expected output for 3D matrix?

Comment: Input : A = val (:,:,1) = [ 2 2 2 0 0 1 1]

Comment: Input : A(2,7,2)--> = val (:,:,1) = [ 2 2 2 0 0 1 1; 0 0 2 2 2 1 1]; val(:,:,2) = [ 1 1 2 2 2 0 0; 0 1 1 0 2 2 2]. so it will create 2 outputs which has size (2,7,2)--> result{1} = the answer has 2 value matrix --> val (:,:,1) and val (:,:,1). and result {2} = the answer also has 2 value matrix --> val (:,:,1) and val(:,:,2). did you understand?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: yes thanks, I updated my code. The idea is add yet another loop over the pages of the matrix (third dimension)